# How to best use non-concurrent futures?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

In my program

1. Objects are created expensively,
2. later modified expensively, and
3. finally, objects are used to generate debugging output in a very distant area of the code

My main goal is to only to execute the creation and modification if debugging. To keep the code cleaner, I want to avoid passing the same condition to all three places and instead make sure that the object is only created and modified if it is used (as opposed to when it is supposed to be used because that creates potential for code rot).

One way of doing that would be use `concurrent.futures`. However, that comes with the overhead of creating a thread / process that would have to be paid even if not debugging. I want to avoid that (and I can live with not having the upside of speed up, because I would only benefit when debugging, i.e. when expections to speed are anyways relaxed).

My idea is to use a "non-concurrent future", which would have little overhead on creation and modification and would only cost if actually used. It would be relatively simple to derive a `SynchronousExecuter` from `concurrent.futures.Executor` - would that be my best option?

One alternative I can see is working with generators, but that gets unwieldy a. because they are aimed at sequences where I need a single object and b. because the object is modified later on.

Another idea would be a dedicated proxy-class. That would be more involved than generators on generation, but transparent on use. Only downside: it doesn't work with overloaded operators.

```
#!Python
from pathlib import Path # arbitrary class to try out functionality
from typing import Any

class Delayed:
    def __init__(self, f, args=[], kwargs={}):
        self.__o = None
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __getattr__(self, __name: str) -> Any:
        if self.__o is None:
            f = self.f
            args = self.args
            kwargs = self.kwargs
            del self.f
            del self.args
            del self.kwargs
            self.__o = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.__o.__getattribute__(__name)
    

p = Delayed(Path, ('.',))
p.parent
p.absolute()
p / 'foo' # error
```

Which would be the cleanest option?